# Cloning Repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, repository

I have installed GIT on VS2010

I am comfused with tools of GIT.

When clicking on:

```
GIT->Clone Repository
```

Does cloning repository means that we will upload files of the repository?

Is Commit tool the opposite way of cloning: uploading files in the repository?

Comment: You probably need to read something about [Git](http://git-scm.com/book) and version controlling

Comment: You can use Git Bash for testing purpose. Your "Windows" tool is just a frontend that invoke the basic commands, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, cloning mean you download the files of your repository.

Commit is a tool to save your modifications, but to upload file into your repository, you need to use the Push tool

Comment: Is there a way to upload files on a server directly, without doing it via Visual Studio?